# What is the area o of the triangle with the legs lowered on its sides?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to solve a problem and got stuck in the following:

Point $P$ is a point inside triangle $ABC$ that satisfies the following conditions:

$$\angle BPC-\angle BAC=\angle APC-\angle ABC=\angle APB-\angle BCA$$ and $\angle BAC=60 \text{degrees}$ and length of $AP=12$ units.

What is the area of the triangle whose vertices are lowered from the point $P$ to the sides $AB, BC$, and $CA$?

I have no idea for this question.

Comment: @trula "are lowered" probably means "are the orthogonal projections". deepblue, could you confirm ?

Comment: Have you been able to construct such a point $P$ (by trial and error) for example with Geogebra ?

Comment: Yes,"lowered" means " the orthogonal projections." I don't know usuing any drawing program.

Comment: Your conditions do not determine a unique point $P$. Considering the particular case where $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle and $P$ is its center of gravity.

Comment: As Prof. @JeanMarie has speculated in comments, point $\space P\space$ exists for all sorts of scalene triangles. It is the triangle center listed in ETC as $\text{X}_{15}\space 1^{\text{st}}\space\text{Isodynamic Point}$. It is also the isogonal conjugate of the famous $\text{X}_{13}\space \text{Fermat Point}$. However, if the largest vertex angle of the triangle is greater than $\space 120^o$, point $\space P\space$ lies outside the triangle. The pedal triangle of $\space P\space$ is always equilateral. Do you want us to compile an answer, which includes a method to construct $\space P$?

Comment: @YNK Very interesting. Please, indeed, tranform your comment into an answer that I will be happy to upvote.

Comment: @YNK Wikipedia has a very interesting article on this [isodynamic point $X_{15}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isodynamic_point).

Comment: I am going to give an answer tomorrow with an explicit formula for the area.

Answer (score 1):

[image: X15]

Any triangle, the largest vertex angle of which is less than $120^o$, has a point $P$ in its interior that satisfies the conditions mentioned in OP’s problem statement. This point is known to triangle-geometers as $\text{X}_{15}\space 1^{\text{st}}\text{ Isodynamic Point}$ (see [ETC](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/etc.html)). This is also one of the isogonal conjugates of the famous $\text{X}_{13}\space \text{Fermat Point}$. It lies on the Brocard axis of the reference triangle and its pedal triangle is equilateral (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$).

There are various constructions to locate this point in a given triangle, e.g.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isodynamic_point). $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$ shows a simple construction that is most appropriate to the scenario on hand. Triangle $ABC$ is the given scalene triangle and it is usually called the reference triangle by triangle-geometers. First calculate (or construct) the three angles, such that,
$$\omega = 60^o+\measuredangle A\qquad\theta = 60^o+\measuredangle B\quad \text{and}\quad\phi = 60^o+\measuredangle C\qquad.$$

Now, construct three isosceles triangles $CVB$, $AUC$, and $BWA$, which have $\space\omega$, $\space\theta,\space$ and $\space\phi\space$ as their apex angles respectively. When we draw the circumcircles of these three isosceles triangles, they intersect at a common point, which is the sought point $P$.

Let us get back to OP’s question. Even with $\measuredangle A=60^o$, it is very difficult to determine the area of the mentioned triangle unless one assumes that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral. That is exactly what @Piquito has done in his answer. Therefore, we are of the opinion that OP should accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

We are indebted to @YNK who has shown that this point is the remarkable (internal) [isodynamic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isodynamic_point) $X_{15}$. See as well $X_{15}$ [here](http://math.fau.edu/yiu/PSRM2015/yiu/New%20Folder%20(4)/Backup060110/EdwardBrisse/ETC050103.html) in the ETC (Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers).

I will go further by using trilinear coordinates (and converting them to cartesian coordinates) in order to reach an explicit expression for the side $s$ of (equilateral !) triangle DEF made by the feet of the perpendiculars issued from point $X_{15}$ to the sides of $ABC$.

Knowing $s$, the area of triangle $DEF$ is easily obtained.

It is not the place to describe what are [trilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates). It is enough to say that they are "cousin coordinates" of the better known barycentric coordinates with the following connection :

$$\text{(trilinear coord. )}  \ (x,y,z) \ \leftrightarrow \ \text{(barycentric coord. )} (ax,by,cz)  \tag{1}$$

where $a=BC,b=CA,d=AB$.

Therefore, trilinear coordinates and cartesian coordinates can be placed in correspondence as follows :

$$\text{(trilinear coord. )} \ (x,y,z) \  \ \leftrightarrow$$ $$\text{(cartesian coord. )} \
\frac{axA+bxB+cxC}{ax+by+cz}\tag{2}$$

Let $$\begin{cases}
p&:=&\sin(\hat{A}+\pi/3)\\
q&:=&\sin(\hat{B}+\pi/3)\\
r&:=&\sin(\hat{C}+\pi/3)
\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

The trilinear coordinates of $X_{15}, D, E, F$ are known to be (see the references mentionned at the beginning of this answer) resp. :

$$\begin{cases}
X_{15} : &(p,&q,&r&)\\
D : &(0,&q+p\cos(\hat{C}),&r+p\cos(\hat{B})&)\\
E : &(p+q\cos(\hat{C}),&0,&r+q\cos(\hat{A})&)\\
F : &(p+r\cos(\hat{B}),&q+r\cos(\hat{A}),&0&)
\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

With all these ingredients, we get :

$$D=\frac{b(q+p \cos(\hat{C}))B+c(r+p \cos(\hat{B}))C}{b(q+p \cos(\hat{C}))+c(r+p \cos(\hat{B}))}$$

$$E=\frac{a(p+q \cos(\hat{C}))A+b(r+q \cos(\hat{A}))C}{a(p+q \cos(\hat{C}))+b(r+q \cos(\hat{A}))}$$

which are resp. equivalent to :

$$\vec{CD}=\frac{b(q+p \cos(\hat{C}))}{b(q+p \cos(\hat{C}))+c(r+p \cos(\hat{B}))}\vec{CB}\tag{5}$$

$$\vec{CE}=\frac{a(p+q \cos(\hat{C}))}{a(p+q \cos(\hat{C}))+c(r+q \cos(\hat{A}))}\vec{CA}\tag{6}$$

By difference between (6) and (7), we are able to express $\vec{DE}$ (therefore its norm $s$, the looked-for sidelength) :
as a function of known quantities :

$$\vec{DE}=\tfrac{a(p+q \cos(\hat{C}))}{a(p+q \cos(\hat{C}))+c(r+q \cos(\hat{A}))}\vec{CA}-\tfrac{b(q+p \cos(\hat{C}))}{b(q+p \cos(\hat{C}))+c(r+p \cos(\hat{B}))}\vec{CB}\tag{7}$$

In the Matlab program below which has generated Fig. 1, we have used complex quantities giving the value of $s$ as a side-result, instead of having it at once by using "big formula" (7).

[image]

Sanity check : if $ABC$ is equilateral, $p=q=r=\sqrt{3}/2$ ; a routine verification shows that (7) is reduced to $\vec{ DE}=\tfrac12 \vec{BA}$$.

```
clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;axis([-1,1,-1,1]);axis off
% Vertices $A,B,C$ can be assumed WLOG to lay on the unit circle :
alpha=17*pi/12;beta=17*pi/9;gamma=11*pi/15; % for example
A=exp(i*alpha);
B=exp(i*beta);
C=exp(i*gamma);
V1=[A,B,C];
plot([V1,V1(1)],'r','linewidth',5);
a=abs(B-C);b=abs(C-A);c=abs(B-A);
Aa=pi+(gamma-beta)/2;
Ba=(alpha-gamma)/2;
Ca=(beta-alpha)/2;
p=sin(Aa+pi/3);
q=sin(Ba+pi/3);
r=sin(Ca+pi/3);
% transformation trilinear -> cartesian :
tri2car=@(t)((a*t(1)*A+b*t(2)*B+c*t(3)*C)/(a*t(1)+b*t(2)+c*t(3)));
Xc=tri2car([p,q,r]);
Dc=tri2car([0,q+p*cos(Ca),r+p*cos(Ba)]);
Ec=tri2car([p+q*cos(Ca),0,r+q*cos(Aa)]);
Fc=tri2car([p+r*cos(Ba),q+r*cos(Aa),0])
s=abs(Dc-Ec), % s = 0.798325880115807 in our case.
plot([Xc,Dc,Xc,Ec,Xc,Fc],'-ok');
V2=[Dc,Ec,Fc];
text(real(V1)+[-0.1,0.1,-0.1],imag(V1)+[-0.1,0,0.1],{'A','B','C'})
text(real(V2)+[0.05,-0.15,0],imag(V2)+[0.1,0,-0.1],{'D','E','F'})
text(real(Xc)+0.05,imag(Xc),'X')
plot([V2,V2(1)],'g','linewidth',5)
```

Comment: Many studies have been done of isodynamic points  : for example this one http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/Isodynamic.pdf

Comment: You have forgotten to tell us about the two points $\pmb{L}$ and $\pmb{M}$.

Comment: @YNK oops ! I had changed notations but forgotten those L (alias D) and M (alias E). I am going to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$$\angle{BPC}+\angle{APC}+\angle{APB}=360^{\circ}\\\angle{BAC}+\angle{ABC}+\angle{ACB}=180^{\circ}$$ This suggest the answer $\triangle{ABC}$ equilateral so, by property of medians, of  height equal to $12+\dfrac{12}{2}=18$ and side $12\sqrt3$.

Then the triangle of required area is the equilateral triangle of side $6\sqrt3$.

Comment: I see we are "on the same wavelength". Nevertheless, I wouldn't assert this is "the" solution : I think there are other solutions...